# Нет public полей в инспекторе Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос заключается в том что поля класса скрипта, привязанного к GameObject, не отображается в инспекторе.
Скрипт в инспекторе:

[image: Отображение скрипта в инспекторе]

Часть скрипта (начало):

```
public class SphereCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Sprite Red;
    public static Sprite Green;
    public static Sprite Blue;

    public GameObject Slot;
    public GameObject Canvas;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Unity` не отображает `static` переменные:

```
public Sprite Red;
    public Sprite Green;
    public Sprite Blue;
```

Если вы хотите изменять эти переменные из другого скрипта, то:

1. В скрипте, из которого хотите что-либо изменять в другом скрипте, вам нужно создать публичную переменную скрипта, в котором хотите что-либо изменять, в вашем случае будет это выглядить так:

```
public SphereCounter sc;
```

2. В эдиторе, перетащить в появившиеся поле, объект на котором весит скрипт: `SphereCounter`

Далее вы можете обращаться ко всему, что находится в скрипте `SphereCounter`, например так:

```
sc.Red = Color.Red;
```